# Singleton-valued correspondence that is upper hemicontinuous "induces" a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that the correspondence $F:X\rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^K$, $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^L$ nonempty, which is singleton-valued and upper hemicontinuous (defined below) "induces" a continuous function. By "induces" I mean that I can build a continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^K$ from the given correspondence.

My attempt: Clearly since $F$ is singleton-valued we can define the function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^K$ as that the value in that singleton of $F$, i.e., let $x\in X$ then $F(x)=\{y\}$, hence we define $f(x)=y$.

Now, in order to show that $f$ is continuous, let $x\in X$, and $(x_n)$ be in $X$ such that $x_n\to x$, clearly $f(x)=y$ for some $y\in\mathbb{R}^L$. We can define the sequence $(y_n)=(f(x_n))$, clearly $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, y_n\in F(x_n)$. Then by uhc there exists a *subsequence* $(y_{n_m})$ with  $y_{n_m}\to y$, i.e.,  $f(x_{n_m})\to f(x)$ (because $y\in F(x)$).

That looks so close! I'm only missing that in order for $f$ to be continuous it must be the sequence $(y_n)$ itself what converges to $y$ and not a subsequence.

Any hint in how to advance from this point is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Definition (upper hemicontinuous, uhc):** A correspondence $F:X\rightrightarrows\mathbb{R}^K$, $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^L$ nonempty, is upper hemicontinuous at $x\in X$ if for all sequences $(x_n)$ in $X$ with $x_n\to x$ and $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^K$ with $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},y_n\in F(x_n)$ we have that there exists a subsequence $(y_{n_m})$ of $(y_n)$ such that $y_{n_m}\to y$ and $y\in F(x)$.

Comment: Start from the definition of convergence: $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N: |f(x_n)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$, and try to prove it by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $F:X\rightrightarrows\mathbb{R}^L$ is singleton-valued and upper hemicontinuous, and that the function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^L$ defined by $f(x)\in F(x)$ is not continuous.

Then, we have that for some $x\in X$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)\cap X$ with $\|f(x_n)-f(x)\|\ge\varepsilon$. From the previous statement we can build a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ with $x_n\to x$, and the property that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}, \|f(x_n)-f(x)\|\ge\varepsilon$. Notice that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $f(x_n)\in F(x_n)$ by definition. Now, since $F$ is upper hemicontinuous then there exists a subsequence $f(x_{n_m})$ with $f(x_{n_m})\to y$ for some $y\in F(x)$. Clearly $y=f(x)$, and by convergence of the subsequence since $\varepsilon>0$, then for some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\|f(x_{n_0})-f(x)\|<\varepsilon$, which is a contradiction.